# How to play a notification sound programatically using the URI without setting it to default?

Tags: android, uri, android-notifications

I am using the following code to get the list of notification sounds available on the android device:

```
public static ArrayList<String> getNotificationSounds(Activity curActivity) {
    RingtoneManager manager = new RingtoneManager(curActivity);
    manager.setType(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    Cursor cursor = manager.getCursor();

    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        String id = cursor.getString(RingtoneManager.ID_COLUMN_INDEX);
        String uri = cursor.getString(RingtoneManager.URI_COLUMN_INDEX);
        String name = cursor.getString((RingtoneManager.TITLE_COLUMN_INDEX));

        list.add(name);
    }

    return list;
}
```

Now I want to play one of these notification sounds (no image, or title), **just the sound** *without* setting it as default.

I have seen many solutions which suggest setting a sound as default using

```
RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(this,RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION,soundClipUri);
```

By using this URI that I obtain from the method described above

```
String uri = cursor.getString(RingtoneManager.URI_COLUMN_INDEX);
```

I get an error saying that datasource is not valid.

So , to sum it up,

1) How to play a notification sound without setting it as default?

2) How to obtain and use the Uri of that notification sound?

**EDIT:** When I tried to print the URI from the cursor query mentioned above, I get the same result:

```
content://media/internal/audio/media
```

for all of the available notification sounds.

Are we supposed to append the notification sound title to this and pass the result as the Uri?

Code to play the notification:

```
 Ringtone r = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(getApplicationContext(),uri);
 r.play();
```

Comment: "I get an error saying that datasource is not valid" -- what is the `Uri`? How are you using it?

Comment: Editing my question :)

Comment: @CommonsWare : Please have a look now.

Comment: That does not look like a complete `Uri`, more like a prefix lacking the instance ID at the end.

Comment: So should I append the ID_COLUMN_INDEX value to this to form the complete Uri?

Comment: I have no idea -- I haven't worked with `RingtoneManager`. I was looking for general `Uri` issues.

Comment: Got it to work, thanks for your input @CommonsWare

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a solution to my problem.

I need to append the notification sound's ID to the URI returned by that method so that the internal notification sound can be properly located.

Here is the solution, I get the notification sound's URI and play it using the following code:

```
 try 
     {
        Ringtone r = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(getApplicationContext(), PhoneUtils.getNotificationSoundUri(getApplicationContext(), getSoundClipID()));
        r.play();
     }
     catch (Exception e)
     {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Ringtone r = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(getApplicationContext(), RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION), getSoundClipID()));
       r.play();

     }
```

Code for the getNotification sound URI method:

```
public static Uri getNotificationSoundUri(Context context,String soundClipId)
{
    RingtoneManager manager = new RingtoneManager(context);
    manager.setType(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    Cursor cursor = manager.getCursor();

    ArrayList<NotificationSound> list = new ArrayList<>();
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        if(soundClipId.equals(cursor.getString(RingtoneManager.ID_COLUMN_INDEX)))
        {
            return Uri.parse(cursor.getString(RingtoneManager.URI_COLUMN_INDEX)+"/"+cursor.getString(RingtoneManager.ID_COLUMN_INDEX));
        }

    }

    return RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
}
```